# Where can I ask a question about Microsoft's partner program?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange site could I ask the following question:

> Does a Microsoft Partner have authorization, distribution agreement, licensing agreement or any other documents that can prove that “Microsoft” has granted its partner to sell products?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because were we to suggest a site they would say that product support questions (without programming, configuration, usage, etc.) are off topic - and refer you to the duplicate explaining that. --- If you need to call "Customer Service" that's what you need to do, we can't speak to legal agreements.

Comment: @Cerbrus -  I wouldn't ask here if they give me a response. I already tried sending emails to some of Microsoft's Partner from this link but I didn't get any response. https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-nz/reseller

Comment: @Rob Just because the *answer* is that this question isn't suitable for any SE site doesn't mean that this post is not on-topic for this site.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog True. But as Glorfindel reminds us: the OP here didn't ask "where to ask X". He asked us about X directly. And when he was told "you are off topic on the whole network", the OP came back "but my problem is X".

Answer (score 11):

That's a question for [Microsoft (partner) support](https://partner.microsoft.com/support), not for Stack Exchange.